# RxJs: buffer events when condition is true, pass events through when condition is false

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

I created the Observable constructor below that works as described. Does anyone know if there is a more concise way of achieving the same behaviour using the operators that come with RxJs? I was looking at [bufferToggle](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-bufferToggle) which is close to the required behaviour, but I need the emitted values to be passed through when the buffer is closed.

**Function Description:** Buffers the emitted `source` values if the `condition` emits `true`, and passes through the emitted `source` values if the `condition` emits `false`. If the condition emits `false` after being `true`, the buffer releases each value in the order that they were received. The buffer is initialised to pass through the emitted `source` values until the `condition` emits `true`.

```js
function bufferIf<T>(condition: Observable<boolean>, source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return new Observable<T>(subscriber => {
    const subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    const buffer = [];
    let isBufferOpen = false;

    subscriptions.push(
      // handle source events
      source.subscribe(value => {
        // if buffer is open, or closed but buffer is still being 
        // emptied from previously being closed.
        if (isBufferOpen || (!isBufferOpen && buffer.length > 0)) {
          buffer.push(value);

        } else {
          subscriber.next(value);
        }
      }),

      // handle condition events
      condition.do(value => isBufferOpen = value)
        .filter(value => !value)
        .subscribe(value => {
          while (buffer.length > 0 && !isBufferOpen) {
            subscriber.next(buffer.shift());
          }
        })
    );

    // on unsubscribe
    return () => {
      subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
    };
  });
}
```

## Edit

In response to comment, the following is the same function as the one above but in the form of an RxJs Operator and updated to use RxJx 6+ pipeabale Operators:

```ts
 function bufferIf<T>(condition: Observable<boolean>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
   return (source: Observable<T>) => {
     return new Observable<T>(subscriber => {
       const subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
       const buffer: T[] = [];
       let isBufferOpen = false;
   
       subscriptions.push(
         // handle source events
         source.subscribe(value => {
           // if buffer is open, or closed but buffer is still being 
           // emptied from previously being closed.
           if (isBufferOpen || (!isBufferOpen && buffer.length > 0)) {
             buffer.push(value);
           } else {
             subscriber.next(value);
           }
         }),
   
         // handle condition events
         condition.pipe(
          tap(con => isBufferOpen = con),
          filter(() => !isBufferOpen)
         ).subscribe(() => {
          while (buffer.length > 0 && !isBufferOpen) {
            subscriber.next(buffer.shift());
          }
        })
       );
   
       // on unsubscribe
       return () => subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there an implementation that would allow this to be used in a pipe? In the place you would usually use the `buffer`

Comment: Yes there is. See my edit above.

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver! If I could upvote again I would :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution based on operators rather than subscriptions, but hesitate to call it more concise.

Note, the endToken can be removed if it's possible to guarantee the buffer on/off stream always ends with an off (i.e an odd number of emits).

```js
console.clear() 
const Observable = Rx.Observable

// Source and buffering observables
const source$ = Observable.timer(0, 200).take(15)
const bufferIt$ = Observable.timer(0, 500).map(x => x % 2 !== 0).take(6)  

// Function to switch buffering
const endToken = 'end'            
const bufferScanner = { buffering: false, value: null, buffer: [] }
const bufferSwitch = (scanner, [src, buffering]) => { 
  const onBufferClose = (scanner.buffering && !buffering) || (src === endToken)
  const buffer = (buffering || onBufferClose) ? scanner.buffer.concat(src) : []
  const value = onBufferClose ? buffer : buffering ? null : [src]
  return { buffering, value, buffer }
}
      
// Operator chain
const output = 
  source$
    .concat(Observable.of(endToken))     // signal last buffer to emit
    .withLatestFrom(bufferIt$)           // add buffering flag to stream
    .scan(bufferSwitch, bufferScanner)   // turn buffering on and off
    .map(x => x.value)                   // deconsruct bufferScanner
    .filter(x => x)                      // ignore null values
    .mergeAll()                          // deconstruct buffer array
    .filter(x => x !== endToken)         // ignore endToken

// Proof
const start = new Date()
const outputDisplay = output.timestamp()
  .map(x => 'value: ' + x.value + ', elapsed: ' + (x.timestamp - start) )
const bufferDisplay = bufferIt$.timestamp()
  .map(x => (x.value ? 'buffer on' : 'buffer off') + ', elapsed: ' + (x.timestamp - start) )
bufferDisplay.merge(outputDisplay)
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

**Footnote**

I also found a solution based on `buffer()`, but am not convinced it's stable with a high-frequency source. There seems to be something hokey with certain buffer configurations (i.e the declaration looks sound but tests show occasional delays which interfere with buffer operation).

In any case, for reference,

```
/* 
  Alternate with buffered and unbuffered streams
*/

const buffered = 
   source$.withLatestFrom(bufferIt$)      
    .filter(([x, bufferIsOn]) => bufferIsOn)  
    .map(x => x[0])
    .buffer(bufferIt$.filter(x => !x))
    .filter(x => x.length)       // filter out empty buffers
    .mergeAll()                  // unwind the buffer

const unbuffered =
  source$.withLatestFrom(bufferIt$)      
    .filter(([x, bufferIsOn]) => !bufferIsOn)    
    .map(x => x[0])

const output = buffered.merge(unbuffered)
```

Comment: I accepted your answer since you provided a solid solution to the question I asked. I decided however to stay with my original approach (for now at least) since IMO it is easier to understand and the number of operators required to make the operator approach work adds little value. Many thanks for experimenting with this!

Comment: 'easier to understand' - totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

### Using a hot observable

Here's another way, slightly briefer (adding a new answer as the previous is rather busy)

```js
// Source and buffering observables
const source$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 200).take(15)
const bufferIt$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 500).map(x => x % 2 !== 0).take(6)

const makeHot$ = (src) => {
  const hot$ = new Rx.Subject();
  src.subscribe(x => hot$.next(x));
  return hot$;
}

// Buffered output
const buffered$ = (source, bufferIt) => {
  const hot$ = makeHot$(source)
  const close = new Rx.Subject()
  return bufferIt
    .concat(Rx.Observable.of(false))       // ensure last buffer emits
    .do(x => {if(!x) close.next(true)} )   // close previous buffer
    .switchMap(x => x ? hot$.buffer(close) : hot$.map(x=>[x]))
    .mergeAll()
}

// Proof
const start = new Date()
const outputDisplay = buffered$(source$, bufferIt$).timestamp()
  .map(x => 'value: ' + x.value + ', elapsed: ' + (x.timestamp - start) )
const bufferDisplay = bufferIt$.timestamp()
  .map(x => (x.value ? 'buffer on' : 'buffer off') + ', elapsed: ' + (x.timestamp - start) )
bufferDisplay.merge(outputDisplay)
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently looking for a similar solution and finally came up with this.

May help others, assuming some debounce time is acceptable (perhaps desirable)

```
source$.pipe(buffer(source$.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  filter(condition)
)))
```