# RXJS buffer but only occasionally

Tags: javascript, angular, audio, rxjs

Scenario:

I receive audio bytes as an array, and need to play in order. The data is continuously arriving, so I use an observable to receive it.  Since it takes less time to receive the data than to play it, I want to use a buffer to store the bytes while audio is being played, and only play it afterwards.

My code:

Observable subscription:

```
 audioObservable.pipe(
        buffer(this.audioDoneSubject), // problematic line
        map(matrix => { // since buffer creates an array that I want to flatten
          let a = [];
          matrix.forEach(ar => {
            a = a.concat(ar);
          });
          return a;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(arr => this.playAsync(arr, 1, 44100));
```

and the playAsync method is :

```
async playAsync(arr: number[], channelCount: number, sampleRate) {
    const context = new AudioContext();
    const buffer = context.createBuffer(channelCount, arr.length, sampleRate);
    const floatArray = new Float32Array(arr);
    buffer.copyToChannel(floatArray, 0);
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start();
    source.onended = (event) => this.audioDoneSubject.next(event);
  }
```

My problem is twofold:

1. The flow stops at the buffer, since audioDone has never emitted since we have not yet played anything.

This I can work around by using a replay subject and calling `this.audioDoneSubject.next()` after the first emit to my `audioObservable` and the subscription. But this brings me to the second issue

2. When audio is finished, `this.audioDoneSubject` emits, so the buffer releases, even if no new data has come in.  If more data has come in, it works fine - it plays the data and the flow continues. However, if no new data has come in, then `playAsync` gets called with an empty array and throws an exception for not being able to properly create the audio buffer.

How can I tell the pipe buffer to only buffer if I am currently playing audio, and if I'm not, if the audio resource is free, to just skip to the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47242559/14492841) shows how to write a `bufferIf` pipe that can be used to accomplish this